# CSS Polygon Shadow

Tags: css, svg, shadow, clipping

I'm using the `clip-path` property to shape my block element.

```
clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100px, 50% 100%, 0 100px);
```

I would like to put a "drop shadow" in that element. So, I've tried some techniques, like:

```
box-shadow: 0 15px 30px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
```

Or...

```
filter: drop-shadow(0 15px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5));
```

[See my test environment on CodePen.](https://codepen.io/caio/pen/zwoqXX)

Is it possible with CSS or SVG?

Comment: The only `box-shadow` you can have on a clip-path is inset. The normal one is outside the element, hence getting clipped.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu, `box-shadow` kept hidden even using the `clip-path: inset(0)` (test only).

Comment: best would be to use an svg or give a try to a gradient https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BRQzbq

Comment: The [box-shadow](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-backgrounds-3/#box-shadow) would be `inset`, @CaioTarifa, not the `clip-path`. You can always use `clip-path` on your element while wrapping it inside the same parent with `position:relative` along with an `svg` with `position:absolute` added solely for the purpose of getting the box-shadow effect.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu, my bad, you're right. I don't know if I understand, but I'll try.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As it was said in the comments, you need 2 nested elements for this, the inner for the clipping and the outer for the shadow.

```css
body {
  background-color: gray;
}

.navigation {
  filter: drop-shadow(0 15px 30px rgba(0, 0, 200, 0.5));
}

.innernav {
  /* PATH */
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100px, 50% 100%, 0 100px);
  
  
  /* OTHERS */
  background-color: silver;
  color: white;
  height: 150px;
  position: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
}

.main {
  padding: 200px 20px 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navigation"><div class="innernav">Hi, I'm a nav.</div></nav>

<main class="main">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates quia velit modi veniam! Velit fuga facilis blanditiis iure aperiam cumque quasi officia quaerat dignissimos neque repellat quisquam voluptates sequi, hic?</p>
</main>
```